# Map addAll Overwrite in For-Loop Dart

Tags: flutter, for-loop, dart, iteration, overwrite

I have problem with Map iteration.

I tried this

```
List testList = [];
Map<String, dynamic> testMap = new Map;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    testMap.addAll({'name': 'name $i'});
    testList.add(testMap);
  }
print(testList);
```

from what i understand is this code equal to,

```
testList.add({'name': 'name 0'});
testList.add({'name': 'name 1'};
testList.add({'name': 'name 2'});
```

second code worked just fine and give the result i expected, but the first code doesn't. and here is what the first result come.

```
[{name: name 2}, {name: name 2}, {name: name 2}]
```

so the addAll is adding new while overwrite the previous. i tried another approach like `testMap['name']='name $i';`
but it didn't work.
I wonder what did i do wrong. Or is there better way?

[dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/5d0db5072c9cb29cf221632e49278822)

Comment: The code is not equivalent.  The version with `addAll` clobbers the existing `name` entry in `testMap` on each iteration, and it adds three references to the same `testMap` instance to `testList`.  Your second version adds three separate `Map` instances to `testList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this case in dart is pass by reference, you need to create 'new' Map in each loop. Like

```
List testList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    Map<String, dynamic> testMap = new Map();
    testMap.addAll({'name': 'name $i'});
    testList.add(testMap);
  }
print(testList);
```

Comment: it worked just fine. thank you for your help sir. i didnt know it stored not as value but as variable instead.

Comment: Dart does not pass by reference. Dart pass by value where passed value is a refrence to object. This is because all values in Dart are refrences.. This creates an illusion for those who are new to programming in languages like C or C ++. In C (or C ++), you can also pass a reference by value, but this will not mean that you passed a reference by reference.. Don't mislead people if you don't know how Dart works.